# Jquery time event listener stop/start

Tags: javascript, jquery, c#-4.0

I have jQuery plugin I built that is.

```
var timer = $.timer(function() {
    refreshDashboard();
});    
timer.set({ time : 10000, autostart : true });
```

it will call refreshDashboard(); function after 10 seconds. I want to stop timer for 20 minutes from C# code or call javascript function from C#. after 20 minutes it should be start after 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm assuming your javascript is executed client-side, there isn't a way to call the function from C# itself every 20 minutes.

If you'd like the code to execute on page load after 10 seconds, then every 20 minutes (and 10 seconds) after that, you can use an interval - noting that I'm working under the assumption that your `set()` method will kick off the timer:

```
// Set up the timer.
var timer = $.timer(function() {
    refreshDashboard();
});

// Run the initial `set` on load.
timer.set({ time : 10000, autostart : true });

// Run `set()` every 20 minutes.
setInterval(function() {
   timer.set({ time : 10000, autostart : true });
}, 1200000);
```

For what it's worth, Javascript already has it's own 'timer' function, the above can be achieved with:

```
var timer = function() {
    setTimeout(refreshDashboard, 10000);
};

// Run first timer on load.
timer();

// Run again every 20 mintues.
setInterval(timer, 1200000);
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. I have reset the autostart value and its working.